# Biden recently vehemently rejected support from some far-right or racist personality; who was that and what was the rejection?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, joe-biden

I've read in the last week or so that some far rightist or open racist personality denounced Trump's service to America and gave public support to Biden instead.

Biden or his campaign immediately released a scathing rejection of this support.

I can't remember the personality, date, or exact wording of the rejection and am not finding it in Google.

My goal is to find the rejection text.  A link to that would be appreciated, otherwise clues such as the personality's name also appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

The personality was Richard Spencer.  His tweet Sunday:

> "I plan to vote for Biden and a straight democratic ticket.  It's not
> based on 'accelerationism' or anything like that; the liberals are
> clearly more competent people."

Biden's campaign almost immediately responded to that tweet with:

> "When Joe Biden says we are in a battle for the soul of our nation
> against vile forces of hate who have come crawling out from under
> rocks, you are the epitome of what he means.  What you
> stand for is absolutely repugnant. Your support is 10,000% percent
> unwelcome here."

This Spencer character has been in the news several times.  After Trump took office, he shouted "hail Trump" and people present gave Nazi salutes.  He was also scheduled to speak at the Charlottesville counter-rally that ended with the death of a protester in favor of removing Confederate monuments.  Spencer called for "peaceful ethnic cleansing."

I see no record of Trump's campaign ever rejecting Spencer's support.

https://www.businessinsider.com/joe-biden-campaign-disavows-richard-spencer-endorsement-2020-8

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Is 10% unwelcome in the original source? :)

Comment: @gerrit, it is 10,000%.  https://twitter.com/AndrewBatesNC/status/1297739715056144385

Comment: @gerrit the US uses a comma as the thousands separator, not the decimal separator as in some other countries. Therefore the source should be read as ten thousand percent, not ten percent with three places of precision.

Comment: Oh, good eyes Joel.  I lived six years in Switzerland and am used to the decimal comma (and a thousands separator of single-quote or "Hochkomma").  But out of a German context I didn't note the possibility of misunderstanding.